# How to set camel File component timeout

Tags: apache-camel

I want to read a file within a route, but if the file is not present to fail, or timeout.

```
 from("file:someFolder")
                .to("bean:myBean")
```

I then need to proceed to start other routes, depending on how the above went.

I know this is a ridiculously simple requirement but having trawled through Camel In Action and loads of posts it's escaping me...
there seems to be every option imaginable re polling, but none to handle the file never being found or a timeout as far as I can see.

The closest I can find is a consumerTemplate but I don't see how that could fit...once I call camelContext.start() the route starts so I don't see how a consumerTemplate would fit with this.

Any help appreciated before I jump out of the window!

Regards
Mr Tea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the file consumer to send an empty file if there was no files to pickip, see the option sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle on the file documentation at

- http://camel.apache.org/file2